# Add child to root XElement in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add a node to root element in XML file with XDocument.Load . The problem is that it reapeats the header when I add a new node.
Here is the function to create XML file:

```
private void createDoc()
        {
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("Items", new XComment("Here will be added new nodes")));
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
              if (isoStore.FileExists("positions2.xml"))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("File Exists!!!");
                    isoStore.DeleteFile("positions.xml");
                }              
                else
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
                        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("positions2.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
                    {
                        doc.Save(isoStream);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
```

From here everything looks fine and the output is ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Items>
      <!--Here will be added new nodes-->
    </Items>
```

To add a child to the root node I use this function:

```
private void AppendToXMLFile(string reg, string butname, int oldposition, int newposition)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("positions2.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                    var newElement = new XElement("channel",
                       new XElement("region", reg),
                       new XElement("name", butname),
                       new XElement("oldposition", oldposition),
                       new XElement("newpostions", newposition));
                    doc.Element("Items").Add(newElement);  //add node to root node
                    doc.Save(isoStream, SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the output after the `AppendToXMLFile` function is called :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Items>
  <!--Here will be added new nodes-->
</Items><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Items>
  <!--Comment to prevent <Items />-->
  <channel>
    <region>test</region>
    <name>test1</name>
    <oldposition>6</oldposition>
    <newpostions>0</newpostions>
  </channel>
</Items>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the XDocument operations (they are OK) but you Append the new file to the old one.

The relevant parts of the problem:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = 
       new IsolatedStorageFileStream("positions2.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
{
    // A: read it and leave Strean.Position at the end
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);  

    ...  // add Elements

    // B: write the new contents from the last Position (behind the original)
    doc.Save(isoStream, SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);  
}
```

The best solution is to reopen the Stream. Do not reposition, you will have other problems when the file shrinks later.

Roughly, note the FileMode values:

```
XDocument doc;
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = 
       new IsolatedStorageFileStream("positions2.xml", FileMode.Read, isoStore))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);  
}

...  // add Elements

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = 
       new IsolatedStorageFileStream("positions2.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
{
    doc.Save(isoStream, SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to the Xml part of this code at all! You are using the same Stream to read and write the file, so after you load the xml, the file cursor is at the end of the file.
This fix this try using the isoStream.SetLength(0) or isoStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) before calling the doc.Save method (the latter option could leave unwanted text if the new file is smaller than the original one).